# How can I run OpenAPI -> GraphQL conversion?

Tags: javascript, graphql, yarnpkg

I want to convert `.yaml` (OpenAPI) to GraphQL schema (i.e., generate `schema.graphql`) and found 2 converters (scripts) that should help me with that:

- https://github.com/yarax/swagger-to-graphql
- https://github.com/graphql-binding/graphql-binding-openapi

There's a standalone example in each one but since I'm a newbie in JS I can't get it to work. Could anyone post a complete instructions which command should I run to run these repos on my `.yaml` file?

Things that I've tried for [repo #1](https://github.com/yarax/swagger-to-graphql):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/yarax/swagger-to-graphql
$ cd swagger-to-graphql/
$ npm i -g swagger-to-graphql
$ npm i -g graphql # to eliminate the error above
$ swagger-to-graphql --swagger=doc.yaml > types.graphql
$ #doc.yaml is my OpenAPI file that I use as the input
$ swagger-to-graphql (master) $ cat types.graphql
Error: Error opening file "/Users/alex/Dev/temp/swagger-to-graphql/$"
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/alex/Dev/temp/swagger-to-graphql/$'
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/swagger-to-graphql/node_modules/json-schema-ref-parser/lib/resolvers/file.js:51:20)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:230:13)

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/alex/Dev/temp/swagger-to-graphql/$' {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/klinou/Dev/temp/swagger-to-graphql/$',
  toJSON: [Function: errorToJSON],
  inspect: [Function: errorToString]
}
```

And then I receive an error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'graphql'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/swagger-to-graphql/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/swagger-to-graphql/bin/swagger2graphql
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/swagger-to-graphql/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/swagger-to-graphql/bin/swagger2graphql'
  ]
```

Things that I've tried for repo #2:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/graphql-binding/graphql-binding-openapi
$ yarn add graphql-binding-openapi
$ cd example/
$ graphql get-schema
# output: project petstore - endpoint default - No changes
# replace the last line .graphqlconfig.yml
# definition: schema.yaml (to use my input file instead of a sample)
$ graphql get-schema
⚠ Error opening file "/Users/alex/Dev/graphql-binding-openapi/example/$"
```

Comment: Did you look at the example in its Readme?

Comment: There is a standalone example in the documentation:
https://github.com/graphql-binding/graphql-binding-openapi#standalone

Comment: @Dom oh, I see.

Comment: @SLaks could you take another look at the question? I've added some details to it.

Comment: @Dom could you take another look at the question? I didn't manage to run that stand alone example.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest that you use github.com/ibm/openapi-to-graphql? If your OAS (or swagger) is properly formed You can quickly have a GraphQL interface up and running in minutes.

https://github.com/IBM/openapi-to-graphql/blob/master/README.md describes how the CLI works.

Answer (score 0):

You installed `swagger-to-graphql` globally (with `-g`).

Therefore, its peer dependencies must also be installed globally.

Comment: That helps, but still it doesn't generate the final output (see the edit)